# How to write a unit test in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, frameworks

I am new to software testing, and I was wondering how to write a unit test in Typescript.

I know someting about testing, that you have methods like `Asser` or `assertEquals` but how to do this in Typescript and do I need to pay attention the staticly typed classes?

I would like to unit test this funtion

```
function calculateAverage(...numbers: number[]): number {
     let sum = 0
     for (var n in numbers) {
         sum += n
     }
     return sum/numbers.length
}
```

So what framework should I use to produce some test that look like this:

`assertEquals(calculateAverage(1,2,3), 2)` // Actual and expected result

Anyone has an advice for what unit testing framework to use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there are a few javascript testing frameworks, that you can also use in typescript, like mocha or jest. You often need to install the types as dependency, for example

```sh
$ npm i -D @types/mocha
```

but there are also fully in typescript written [testing frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#TypeScript), but the often have a smaller community. So I recommend to start with jest or mocha. I personally prefer mocha in combination with chai as assertion library.
My tests look like this:

```js
it( 'logStack === false', async () => {
    const customOptions: LogUpTsOptions = { quiet: true, logStack: false };
    const logger = new LogUpTs( customOptions );
    expect( await logger.error( new Error( 'first' ) ) ).to.eql( '[ERROR] first' );
    expect( await logger.log( 'second' ) ).to.eql( '[LOG] second' );
} );
```

[tests for logupts](https://github.com/milleniumfrog/logupts/blob/master/src/logupts.spec.ts)

Mocha works in nodejs and the browser (I sometimes use the [karma runner](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma) for testing the browser).

If you run your unit tests in nodejs, I recommend to install the following packages:

- mocha            // mocha as testing framework
- @types/mocha     // needed to use mocha in typescript
- chai             // needed for expect
- @types/chai      // needed to use chai in typescript
- source-map-support // add source-map-support to nodejs
- ts-node          // run typescript directly in nodejs

```sh
$ TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' mocha --opts ./mocha.opts
```

my mocha.opts file:

```
--require ts-node/register
--require source-map-support/register
--recursive
src/**/*.spec.ts
```

If you need something more "works out of the box" I think jest might be the right testing framework for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will play around with these frameworks. Starting with Jest.

Comment: This is a great tutorial for setting up Jest https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/jest.html

Comment: Your link is broken. This one should work: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/jest